# c++ conflicting versions when loading package

Tags: cmake, package, vtk, itk

I know nothing from `c++`. I installed two versions of some package called `ITK`. For some reason, the `4.8` version has its `.cmake` file in `/usr/local/lib/cmake/ITK-4.8/UseITK.cmake` and the `3.16` file `/usr/local/itk/lib/InsightToolkit/UseITK.cmake`.

So now, I am trying to build some project that requires `3.16` version that has in its `CMakeLists.txt` this :

```
find_package(ITK)
...
include( ${ITK_USE_FILE} )
```

but `${ITK_USE_FILE}` is `/usr/local/lib/cmake/ITK-4.8/UseITK.cmake`.
(what I understand is that ITK uses `ITK_USE_FILE` as `Package_INCLUDE_DIR` variable). How can I make `find_package` points to the `3.16` version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that file `/usr/local/itk/lib/InsightToolkit/ITKConfig.cmake` exists and set `ITK_DIR` variable to `/usr/local/itk/lib/InsightToolkit` before finding package:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
...
set(ITK_DIR /usr/local/itk/lib/InsightToolkit)
find_package(ITK)
```

or, if you want your project to work also on other computers, pass this variable to `cmake` call:

```
cmake -DITK_DIR=/usr/local/itk/lib/InsightToolkit (...)
```

(`CMakeLists.txt` remains unchanged in that case).

---

According to the sources, `FindITK.cmake` (triggered with `find_package(ITK)` command) just redirect request to *Config* mode:

```
# FindITK.cmake
...
find_package(ITK ${_ITK_REQUIRED} ${_ITK_QUIET} NO_MODULE
    NAMES ITK InsightToolkit
    CONFIGS ITKConfig.cmake
    )
```

but does not pipe `VERSION` parameter to it. That's why setting version doesn't work.

Setting `ITK_DIR` forces CMake to search `ITKConfig.cmake` firstly under given directory. More details can be found in [find_package documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html).

Comment: sorry I almost know nothing from `c++`. Do you mean setting `cmake -DITK_DIR=` requires to recompile `ITK`. Or is it an argument for my project that requires `ITK` ? Btw, is it possible to set this `ITK_DIR` in `CMakeLists.txt` ?

Comment: It is argument for you project that requires ITK. Yes, you can set variable in your CMakeLists.txt instead: `set(ITK_DIR /use/local/itk)`. BTW, you mean "I almost know nothing from `CMake`"? This is CMake details, not a c++.

Comment: I set `set(ITK_DIR "/use/local/itk")` jsut before  `find_package(ITK)`, and then  `${ITK_USE_FILE}` still points to wrong version `/usr/local/lib/cmake/ITK-4.8/UseITK.cmake`. Am I dong wrong ?

Comment: Does file `/usr/local/itk/lib/InsightToolkit/ITKConfig.cmake` actually exist? Do you perform clean configuration(with empty build directory)? Is `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable not set? (You can check its value via `message()` command).

Comment: btw, setting ` ITK_USE_FILE `  and `ITK_INSTALL_PREFIX ` with absolute paths seems to load `CMakeLists.txt` correctly. Now I have got a bunch of weird `file not found` errors since that the files that appear twice as `somefile.h` and `somefile.txx` are detected (so that the include ITK directory is detected) but the ones that appear only as `somefile.h` without `somefile.txx` are not detected. How can it be ?

Comment: yes `/usr/local/itk/lib/InsightToolkit/ITKConfig.cmake` exists

Comment: Setting `ITK_USE_FILE` directrly is not a cure: `UseITK.cmake` file defines macros and variables accodring to ones, defined in `ITKConfig.cmake`, which is **installation-specific**. Unless you process proper `ITKConfig.cmake` in `find_package` scope, inclusion of `UseITK.cmake` (even from proper ITK installation) doesn't bind you with proper ITK installation.

Comment: can I copy paste all the macros and variables of `ITKConfig.cmake` in `CMakeLists.txt` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88792/discussion-between-tsyvarev-and-newben).

Comment: perfect I am going there

Answer (score 1):

Following the CMake [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html), you can request a specific version of the package to be found. You will need to change the `CMakeLists.txt` from:

```
find_package(ITK)
```

to:

```
find_package(ITK 3.16)
```

Comment: that's does not work because when I installed 3.16 version I did not get any directory with `3.16 tag`. When I reload `CMakeLists.txt` I get this message `Warning:By not providing "Find3.16.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "3.16", but CMake did not find one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "3.16" with any of the following names:
  3.16Config.cmake   3.16-config.cmake`

Comment: @Newben, according to the error message, you trying find a package with name "3.16", like `find_package(3.16)`. But code in the answer is different.

Comment: @Tsyvarev `find_package(ITK 3.16)` does not work. I tried this `set( ITK_USE_FILE "/usr/local/itk/lib/InsightToolkit/UseITK.cmake" )
set( ITK_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/local/itk" )` and this helped to load "CMakeLists.txt" but when I compile the code I get that files are not found despite there are under `ITK_INSTALL_PREFIX`