# How to solve:-1: error: No rule to make target `/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/lib/libopencv_xphoto.so.3.0.0', needed by `xxxxx'. Stop

Tags: cmake, target, opencv3.0

I am trying to use cmake to compile code with OpenCV 3.0 in it.  I tried to make it as simple as possible:

```
project(xxxxx)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
find_package(OpenCV)
message("Libs: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message("Include Dir: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

all I have in my main.cpp is:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
```

and

```
cv::UMat trqw;
```

I get the "No rule to make target" error.  The error suggests that it is looking in the "opencv-3.0.0/lib/" folder which doesn't exist, it should be looking in the "opencv-3.0.0/build/lib/".  Did I do something wrong when I built OpenCV that the CMAKE package looks in the wrong spot, and if not is there a better way for my CMakeLists.txt to direct it to look in the correct folder?  I tried "${OPENCL_LIBRARIES}" in the target_link_libraries call and no change.

Thanks!

----edit----------------

yes, I did have find_package(OpenCV) in my cmakelists.txt as well, thanks! I've also tried find_package(OpenCV 3.0) and find_package(OpenCV 3.0 REQUIRED) with no avail.

----------edit---------------
output of

```
message("Libs: ${OpenCV_LIBS}") # I added it to the orig question
```

Libs: opencv_xphoto;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_tracking;opencv_text;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_stereo;opencv_saliency;opencv_rgbd;opencv_reg;opencv_optflow;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_face;opencv_dpm;opencv_datasets;opencv_ccalib;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_aruco;opencv_adas;opencv_world;opencv_videostab;opencv_videoio;opencv_video;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_shape;opencv_photo;opencv_objdetect;opencv_ml;opencv_imgproc;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_highgui;opencv_hal;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_core;opencv_calib3d

Include Dir:

/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/build;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/include/opencv;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/hal/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/flann/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgproc/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/ml/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/photo/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/reg/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/surface_matching/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/video/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgcodecs/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/shape/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/highgui/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/objdetect/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/optflow/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/superres/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/tracking/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/ts/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/xobjdetect/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/xphoto/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/adas/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/bgsegm/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/bioinspired/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/dpm/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/face/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/features2d/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/line_descriptor/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/saliency/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/text/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/calib3d/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/ccalib/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/datasets/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/rgbd/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/stereo/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/stitching/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videostab/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/modules/world/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/xfeatures2d/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/ximgproc/include;/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/opencv_contrib-master/modules/aruco/include

Comment: Did you forget `find_package(OpenCV)` call? What content of `OpenCV_LIBS` variable?

Comment: I honestly don't know how to find the contents of OpenCV_LIBS, I figured the OpenCV package has that info, perhaps I need to track down that package and see what it says? thanks.

Comment: Just output its value in your CMakeLists.txt after `find_package()` call: `message("Libs: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")`. Aside from linking with OpenCV_LIBS, you should issue `include_directories(${OpenCV_INLCUDE_DIR}` before `add_executable()` call. Value of `OpenCV_INLCUDE_DIR` is also interesting.

Comment: So going down your logic here, I tried: set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS "/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/build/lib/") which did solve THAT problem, but it changed the output of include dirs to just the dir I forced it to use... so the question is now, how do I just append the build/lib folder to the full list? Thanks!

Comment: So, `find_package(OpenCV)` found OpenCV under `/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/`, but this installation is not complete for come reason(library files are absent). If you have installed `OpenCV` by hand under `/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/build`, the simplest way to use it is setting `OpenCV_DIR` to that path(before `find_package()` call). See also that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386349/c-conflicting-versions-when-loading-package/32395573#32395573.

Comment: I see... so I guess the better question is why did I build it that way and how do I do it better in the future!  More to learn, more to learn!!  Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tsyvarez for all the help!

```
set ( OpenCV_DIR   "/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.0.0/build/")
```

before

```
find_package( OpenCV 3.0 REQUIRED)
```

in cmakelists.txt

Thanks!