# How to solve: No rule to make target `/home/xxxxx/opencv-3.4.5/build/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.3.4.5', needed by `xxxxx'. Stop

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I think it is almost the same problem happen with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544749/how-to-solve-1-error-no-rule-to-make-target-home-xxxxx-opencv-3-0-0-lib-lib).

I did the comments and answer of this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544749/how-to-solve-1-error-no-rule-to-make-target-home-xxxxx-opencv-3-0-0-lib-lib), set(OpenCV_DIR xxxxx/opencv-3.4.5/build) added in CMakeLists.txt......but it is still the same error as below.

Could anybody kindly help me? Thank you first!

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

# Enable C++11
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)

# Define project name
project(xxxx)

set(OpenCV_DIR xxxxx/opencv-3.4.5/build)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    config: ${OpenCV_DIR}")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

add_executable(xxxx xxxx.cpp)

target_link_libraries(xxxx ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

And this is log of CMake . Seems it successed.

```
(base) ➜  cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenCV: XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/build (found version "3.4.5") 
-- OpenCV library status:
--     config: XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/build
--     version: 3.4.5
--     libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_cvv;opencv_datasets;opencv_dnn_objdetect;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_hfs;opencv_img_hash;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto
--     include path: XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/build;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/include/opencv;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/core/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/flann/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/hdf/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/imgproc/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/ml/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/phase_unwrapping/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/photo/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/plot/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/reg/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/surface_matching/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/video/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/xphoto/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/dnn/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/freetype/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/fuzzy/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/hfs/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/img_hash/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/imgcodecs/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/shape/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/videoio/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/highgui/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/superres/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/ts/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/bioinspired/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/dnn_objdetect/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/features2d/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/line_descriptor/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/saliency/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/text/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/calib3d/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/ccalib/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/cvv/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/datasets/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/objdetect/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/rgbd/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/stereo/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/structured_light/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/tracking/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/videostab/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/xfeatures2d/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/ximgproc/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/xobjdetect/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/aruco/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/bgsegm/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/dpm/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/face/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/optflow/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/stitching/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/Documents/pyproject/ocr/XXXXX
```

But make failed. log is as below:

```
(base) ➜  make
-- OpenCV library status:
--     config: XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/build
--     version: 3.4.5
--     libraries: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab;opencv_aruco;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_cvv;opencv_datasets;opencv_dnn_objdetect;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_freetype;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hdf;opencv_hfs;opencv_img_hash;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto
--     include path: XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/build;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/include/opencv;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/core/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/flann/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/hdf/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/imgproc/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/ml/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/phase_unwrapping/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/photo/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/plot/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/reg/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/surface_matching/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/video/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/xphoto/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/dnn/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/freetype/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/fuzzy/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/hfs/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/img_hash/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/imgcodecs/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/shape/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/videoio/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/highgui/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/superres/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/ts/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/bioinspired/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/dnn_objdetect/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/features2d/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/line_descriptor/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/saliency/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/text/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/calib3d/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/ccalib/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/cvv/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/datasets/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/objdetect/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/rgbd/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/stereo/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/structured_light/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/tracking/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/videostab/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/xfeatures2d/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/ximgproc/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/xobjdetect/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/aruco/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/bgsegm/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/dpm/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/face/include;XXXXX/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules/optflow/include;XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/modules/stitching/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/Documents/pyproject/ocr/XXXXX
Scanning dependencies of target XXXXX
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/XXXXX.dir/XXXXX.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/build/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.3.4.5', needed by 'XXXXX'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/XXXXX.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/XXXXX.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

======================edit added===========================

there is nothing in build/lib after cmake...

```
(base) ➜  build cd lib 
(base) ➜  lib ll
total 0
(base) ➜  lib pwd
/home/user/Documents/software/opencv-3.4.5/build/lib
(base) ➜  lib
......
(base) ➜  build ll
total 1.7M
drwxrwxrwx 11 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:41 3rdparty
drwxrwxrwx  9 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:41 apps
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:41 bin
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 432K Feb 22 04:41 CMakeCache.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  58K Feb 22 04:41 CMakeDownloadLog.txt
drwxrwxrwx 17 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:41 CMakeFiles
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 7.8K Feb 22 04:41 cmake_install.cmake
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 1.2K Feb 22 04:39 cmake_uninstall.cmake
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 449K Feb 22 04:41 CMakeVars.txt
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:39 configured
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 9.6K Feb 22 04:41 CPackConfig.cmake
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  10K Feb 22 04:41 CPackSourceConfig.cmake
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  604 Feb 22 04:41 CTestTestfile.cmake
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   70 Feb 22 04:39 custom_hal.hpp
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 5.1K Feb 22 04:41 cvconfig.h
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  796 Feb 22 04:41 cv_cpu_config.h
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:41 data
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:41 doc
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:39 downloads
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:41 include
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:41 lib
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 438K Feb 22 04:41 Makefile
drwxrwxrwx 54 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:41 modules
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:41 opencv2
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  18K Feb 22 04:41 OpenCVConfig.cmake
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  418 Feb 22 04:41 OpenCVConfig-version.cmake
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  332 Feb 22 04:39 opencv_data_config.hpp
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 6.8K Feb 22 04:41 OpenCVGenPkgConfig.info.cmake
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  31K Feb 22 04:41 OpenCVModules.cmake
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 2.7K Feb 22 04:41 opencv_python_config.cmake
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  152 Feb 22 04:39 opencv_tests_config.hpp
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  46K Feb 22 04:41 pylint.cmake
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:39 python_loader
drwxrwxrwx 10 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:41 samples
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  650 Feb 22 04:41 setup_vars.sh
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:39 share
drwxrwxrwx  5 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:39 test-reports
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  124 Feb 22 04:39 text_config.hpp
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:41 tmp
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4.0K Feb 22 04:41 unix-install
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 7.8K Feb 22 04:41 version_string.tmp
```

This is the opencv cmake cmd as below:

======================edit added===========================

```
(base) ➜  build cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
            -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/user/Documents/software/installation/OpenCV-3.4.5 \
            -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
            -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
            -D WITH_TBB=ON \
            -D WITH_V4L=ON \
            -D OPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages \
        -D WITH_QT=ON \
        -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
        -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/user/Documents/software/opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules \
        -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

Comment: What's in `XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/build/lib/`? Can you post the output of `ls` in that directory?

Comment: @LayneBernardo nothing is XXXXX/opencv-3.4.5/build/lib/

Comment: How did you build opencv? I just checked and there shouldn't be anything in build/lib, so that's right. But I'm not seeing the same error when building from github and then running the CMakeLists.txt you provided with a dummy .cpp file.

Comment: "How did you build opencv?", build cmd added in question.

Comment: Hmm, weird. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: I will repeat from opencv build to run .cpp once again, if any good news, I will keep posted here.

Comment: The problem seems pango and some other depandency packages are not installed. but I gave up on opencv c++ verison, it cost too much hard space to compile, turn to opencv python version.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, but did you try to change the

```
set(OpenCV_DIR xxxxx/opencv-3.4.5/build)
```

shouldn't it be

```
set(OpenCV_DIR xxxxx/opencv-3.4.5/)
```

Or just try to prebuild opencv and then just link it against your executeable.

EDIT1:

from opencv_root_dir/build

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
# use 3 cores to compile
make -j3
```

then

```
# will install it to /usr/local )
sudo make install
```

add to your cmake file:

```
# adds the lib folder to not specify prefix everytime
link_directories( /usr/local/lib/ ) 
target_link_libraries( "<all opencv libs from /usr/local/lib>" )

# adds the includes (dunno if this needed but had to do it in my project)
# but I think only if opencv includes are not located in your project
# root dir
target_include_directories( "/usr/local/include/opencv" or "/usr/local/include/opencv2"  ) # depends what you use
```

Haven't tested it, but it helped in my project. 
The good thing is you don't have to rebuild all the opencv files everytime. 
Also I used the *.so files to link against. *.a didn't work for me but try it yourself.

Comment: if set(OpenCV_DIR xxxxx/opencv-3.4.5/), it will be error as below:   By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one........

Comment: "prebuild opencv and then just link it against your executeable." could you kindly show little more detail steps? @Dimfred

Comment: I am compiling now and trying it. Will soon post my results.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem seems pango and some other depandency packages are not installed. but I gave up on opencv c++ verison, it cost too much hard space to compile, turn to opencv python version.

Comment: But it solved your problem? Would be great if you upvoted my answer.